# Spring session lazy deserialization

Tags: java, hazelcast, spring-session

I have the following situation, i have a microservice architecture with an api gateway and multiple downstream services, some of these have an independent session and this causes my system to throw expired session exception on random service calls.

Since we cannot rewrite these services from scratch we started by introducing hazelcast so that all services can share the same session.

the problem now is that when a service writes an object of a class that other services don't have in their classpath a deserialization exception is thrown.

to solve this i was thinking that if only the attributes that get accessed from a service get deserialized i could probably avoid the exception and everything should work fine.

Do you know if this is at all possible with spring session, or maybe can suggest another solution that would allow me solve the initial problem?

here is a sample project to reproduce my problem: https://github.com/deathcoder/hazelcast-shared-session

Comment: you should see this issue if you access the whole session or that specific value in the session. Is that the case?

Comment: on second check, it seems Spring access the whole session by id on each request.

Comment: I see the deserialization exception immediately after I insert the object, it seems hazelcast tries to update asap, tomorrow I can provide a sample project if anyone wants to have a go at that

Comment: sure, that'd really help.

Comment: Use a different serialisation strategy - something that doesn't involve Java serialisation (not least because it's slow, bulky and very flakey as you've learnt). For example, serialise as JSON and ignore unknown attributes. Better yet use a real scheme designed for backwards and forwards compatibility like Avro or Protobuf.TL;DR: Stop trying to hack your way to an easy solution and actually do some engineering.

Comment: i added a sample project and started trying all the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I got what's happening: Spring-Session-Hazelcast by default store session updates locally until request completed & when request completed, before returning the response, send everything to the cluster using `EntryProcessor`. `EntryProcessor` requires object classes available on the member who stores that session record and since data is distributed, it's possible some other member stores a session created in another instance. According to what you're saying, not all nodes are identical, don't contain all classes & this causes serialization exception.

What you can do, you can use `User Code Deployment` feature to deploy those missing classes to other members: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/manual/html-single/index.html#member-user-code-deployment-beta

If you're changing object that you're storing in the session, you can set `class-cache-mode` to `OFF` to prevent not caching them but sending with each operation.

Please try & let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: This seems interesting I will try it tomorrow

Comment: Wow - that sounds like a great way to both cause horrific classloader issues and horrific performance issues all at once! Do you have any idea the cost of sending classes with every instance?

Comment: this solution is working in my example, i pushed this on the branch: user-code-deployment

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes, you're right. This is why I said if you're changing the classes then you can disable the caching. It seems davide-buzz enabled caching of loaded classes.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to avoid sessions in the API layer in the first place. They scale poorly. And synchronizing sessions is even less scalable.

Try using *access tokens* instead, for example a [JWT token](https://jwt.io/). A token should contain enough user identity information to load the resources necessary to process the transaction (the resources can be cached).

As for the other state in the session - microservices are self-contained from the process perspective, so all intermediate results should be persisted to the database. But of course I don't know the details of your particular application, so this is just a general thought.

Comment: I agree with you and for Newer services we already do as you suggest but for legacy services it would take a massive refactoring to change the way they use the session. If I could get a quicker solution to work than we could slowly start the process of refactoring those legacy services